# Adding library to node js project developed using Visual studio IDE

Tags: node.js, visual-studio

I have started to learn node js. I am using Visual Studio 2015 as IDE for working on Node JS. What are the steps to include a node js library to the node js project on Visual studio 2015 IDE? Normally I install libraries using

```
npm install library-name
```

I searched for the node js console window but it is not plugged in to the IDE.

Comment: what kind of library,you want to add?

Answer (score 1):

Download the file and then just copy/paste the *.js file in your project and take a reference of it in your design page *.aspx (for ASP.NET) or *.cshtml (for ASP.NET MVC) saying

```
  <script src="~/filename.js"></script>
```